# ValueError: Missing some output keys: {'text'} error in RouterChain and Agents

Tags: python-3.x, langchain, py-langchain

I am new to Langchain. I am trying to connect an agent with LLMRouterChain.

The problem is even though the agent is getting executed it is throwing the following error during returning back the answer. Please help me out.

**
error details:**

```
>>what is physics


> Entering new MultiPromptChain chain...
C:\Users\ShravanKS\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\langchain\chains\llm.py:316: UserWarning: The predict_and_parse method is deprecated, instead pass an output parser directly to LLMChain.
  warnings.warn(
search: {'input': 'what is physics'}

> Entering new AgentExecutor chain...
I need to search for the definition of physics.
Action: Search
Action Input: "definition of physics"
Observation: {'type': 'dictionary_results', 'title': 'Dictionary', 'syllables': 'phys·ics', 'phonetic': '/ˈfiziks/', 'word_type': 'noun'}
Thought:I have found the definition of physics.
Final Answer: Physics is a noun and it is pronounced as /ˈfiziks/.

> Finished chain.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[8], line 1
----> 1 import bot

File ~\Desktop\WorkSpace\AzureChatBotAPI2\bot.py:18
     15         output = simple_chain.run(user_input)
     16         print(output)
---> 18 chatbot()

File ~\Desktop\WorkSpace\AzureChatBotAPI2\bot.py:15, in chatbot()
     13     break
     14 simple_chain = get_router_chain()
---> 15 output = simple_chain.run(user_input)
     16 print(output)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\langchain_core\_api\deprecation.py:145, in deprecated.<locals>.deprecate.<locals>.warning_emitting_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    143     warned = True
    144     emit_warning()
--> 145 return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\langchain\chains\base.py:550, in Chain.run(self, callbacks, tags, metadata, *args, **kwargs)
    548     if len(args) != 1:
    549         raise ValueError("`run` supports only one positional argument.")
--> 550     return self(args[0], callbacks=callbacks, tags=tags, metadata=metadata)[
    551         _output_key
    552     ]
    554 if kwargs and not args:
    555     return self(kwargs, callbacks=callbacks, tags=tags, metadata=metadata)[
    556         _output_key
    557     ]

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\langchain_core\_api\deprecation.py:145, in deprecated.<locals>.deprecate.<locals>.warning_emitting_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    143     warned = True
    144     emit_warning()
--> 145 return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\langchain\chains\base.py:383, in Chain.__call__(self, inputs, return_only_outputs, callbacks, tags, metadata, run_name, include_run_info)
    351 """Execute the chain.
    352 
    353 Args:
   (...)
    374         `Chain.output_keys`.
    375 """
    376 config = {
    377     "callbacks": callbacks,
    378     "tags": tags,
    379     "metadata": metadata,
    380     "run_name": run_name,
    381 }
--> 383 return self.invoke(
    384     inputs,
    385     cast(RunnableConfig, {k: v for k, v in config.items() if v is not None}),
    386     return_only_outputs=return_only_outputs,
    387     include_run_info=include_run_info,
    388 )

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\langchain\chains\base.py:168, in Chain.invoke(self, input, config, **kwargs)
    166 except BaseException as e:
    167     run_manager.on_chain_error(e)
--> 168     raise e
    169 run_manager.on_chain_end(outputs)
    171 if include_run_info:

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\langchain\chains\base.py:163, in Chain.invoke(self, input, config, **kwargs)
    156     self._validate_inputs(inputs)
    157     outputs = (
    158         self._call(inputs, run_manager=run_manager)
    159         if new_arg_supported
    160         else self._call(inputs)
    161     )
--> 163     final_outputs: Dict[str, Any] = self.prep_outputs(
    164         inputs, outputs, return_only_outputs
    165     )
    166 except BaseException as e:
    167     run_manager.on_chain_error(e)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\langchain\chains\base.py:458, in Chain.prep_outputs(self, inputs, outputs, return_only_outputs)
    440 def prep_outputs(
    441     self,
    442     inputs: Dict[str, str],
    443     outputs: Dict[str, str],
    444     return_only_outputs: bool = False,
    445 ) -> Dict[str, str]:
    446     """Validate and prepare chain outputs, and save info about this run to memory.
    447 
    448     Args:
   (...)
    456         A dict of the final chain outputs.
    457     """
--> 458     self._validate_outputs(outputs)
    459     if self.memory is not None:
    460         self.memory.save_context(inputs, outputs)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\langchain\chains\base.py:289, in Chain._validate_outputs(self, outputs)
    287 missing_keys = set(self.output_keys).difference(outputs)
    288 if missing_keys:
--> 289     raise ValueError(f"Missing some output keys: {missing_keys}")

ValueError: Missing some output keys: {'text'}
```

**
RouterChain code:**

```
from langchain.chains.router.multi_prompt_prompt import MULTI_PROMPT_ROUTER_TEMPLATE
from langchain.chains.router.llm_router import LLMRouterChain, RouterOutputParser
from langchain.chains.router import MultiPromptChain
from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate

# custom imports
from .destination_chains import get_destination_chains, get_destination_strings
from llms.azure_openai_llm import build_default_llm
from .agents.simple_agents import simple_search_agent
from .basic_llm_chain import get_default_chain
from prompt_templates.prompts_information import prompt_infos

def get_router_chain(router_chain_type: str = None):
    llm = build_default_llm()
    router_template = MULTI_PROMPT_ROUTER_TEMPLATE.format(destinations=get_destination_strings(prompt_infos))
    router_prompt = PromptTemplate(template=router_template,
                              input_variables=['input'],
                              output_parser=RouterOutputParser())
    router_chain = LLMRouterChain.from_llm(llm,router_prompt, verbose=True)
    chain = MultiPromptChain(router_chain=router_chain, destination_chains=get_destination_chains(prompt_infos, llm), default_chain=get_default_chain(llm), verbose=True)
    return chain
```

**Getting destination chains code:**

```
from langchain.chains import LLMChain, SimpleSequentialChain, SequentialChain
from langchain.prompts.chat import ChatPromptTemplate, HumanMessagePromptTemplate

# custom imports
from llms.azure_openai_llm import build_default_llm
from .agents.simple_agents import simple_search_agent

destination_chains = {}

def get_destination_chains(prompt_infos: list, llm=None):
    for p_info in prompt_infos:
        name=p_info['name']
        prompt_template=p_info['template']
        prompt=ChatPromptTemplate.from_template(template=prompt_template)
        chain=LLMChain(llm=llm, prompt=prompt)
        destination_chains[name]=chain
    destination_chains['search'] = simple_search_agent()
    return destination_chains

def get_destination_strings(prompt_infos: list):
    destination = [f"{p['name']}:{p['description']}" for p in prompt_infos]
    destination_str="\n".join(destination)
    destination_str="\n".join('search: searches google to answer back')
    return destination_str
```

**
Agent code:**

```
from langchain.agents import load_tools, initialize_agent, AgentType
from langchain.agents import get_all_tool_names, create_openai_tools_agent, ZeroShotAgent
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()

# custom imports
from llms.azure_openai_llm import build_default_llm
from memory.basic_memory import get_memory_object
from prompt_templates.basic_prompts import get_agent_prompt

def simple_search_agent():
    '''This is a agent that does search using many tools and return the proper answer back
    Use this agent for generat search'''

    llm = build_default_llm()
    memory = get_memory_object()
    tools = load_tools(['llm-math','serpapi'], llm=llm)
    return initialize_agent(
        tools,
        llm, 
        agent=AgentType.ZERO_SHOT_REACT_DESCRIPTION, 
        memory=memory,
        verbose=True,
        prompt=get_agent_prompt(),
        output_key="text"
    )
```

**chatbot code:**

```
from langchain.agents import AgentExecutor
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()

# custom imports
from chains.agents.simple_agents import  simple_search_agent
from chains.router_chains import get_router_chain

def chatbot():
    while True:
        user_input = input("\n>>")
        if user_input == "exit":
            break
        simple_chain = get_router_chain()
        output = simple_chain.run(user_input)
        print(output)

chatbot()
```

I tried creating new agents and tried out passing output_key = 'text' parameter but still it is not working out.
I want the result to be returned back to the bot without any error.
I want to know what is the reason for the error.

Answer (score 0):

This problem comes when there is no input value passing in routerchain, If you can provide logs from langsmith we can detect problem more easily.
Or you can try this: https://towardsdatascience.com/a-gentle-intro-to-chaining-llms-agents-and-utils-via-langchain-16cd385fca81
which contains same use case.

Currently, i am seeing there are lots of problem in RouterChain, and it's evolving in daily basis. Support of routerchaining is more promising in Nodejs rather than python